# asp.net user control is not displaying: Unrecognized namespace

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

This is how a register the control on the page:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="Pcp" Src="../../Controls/ClientPayement.ascx" %>
```

And this is how I use it:

```
<uc1:Pcp ID = "pcpClient1"></uc1:Pcp>
```

I don't know why uc1 has a green underline warning. **When I hover over it, it says: "Unrecognized namespace** uc1". And the user control is not displaying on the page.

Am I missing something? Yet [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbz9etab%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) says that this is all I need to do.

Comment: "uc1" is not the same thing as "uc"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are specifying a `uc` prefix in `<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" ..` so that's the one you should use:

```
<uc:Pcp ID = "pcpClient1"></uc:Pcp>
```

Or you could change the declared prefix:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Pcp" Src="../../Controls/ClientPayement.ascx" %>
```

And use the control as you posted in the question:

```
<uc1:Pcp ID = "pcpClient1"></uc1:Pcp>
```

---

**EDIT**

As Shai Cohen pointed out in another answer, you are also missing the `runat="server"` from the usercontrol tag.

```
<uc1:Pcp ID = "pcpClient1" runat="server"></uc1:Pcp>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Juan's answer, you are also missing `runat="server"`.